# i need proper way of backing up MYSQL database from Desktop Application to online server

Tags: c#, mysql

first of all i want to clarify that i have been using "mysqldump"and "mysqlbackup" for backing up my data locally but my question is a bit different,
i have POS application and i have multiple users so all of them has their own database i have kept same database name for all of them for now, so what i exactly want is that i have given them a option to backup their database online and i am manually adding each datarow to the online database and i have to make different database for all clients separately which is a big hussle and for sure not a proper way of backing it up
i have my own domain and hosting server on namecheap.com and i have online mysql server in there

so what i want is what is the proper / professional way of backing up data from an desktop app to online servers

that's the current way i am backing up mysql data to online mysql server database

```
var CON_ONLINE = new MySqlConnection(MY_SETTING_ONLINE_CON_STRING);
string TABLE_SQL_BUILDER = @"Insert into `" + TABLE_NAME.ToLower() + "` values " + TABLE_DATA_FORMAT;
CON_ONLINE.Open();
string LAST_RECORD = Strings.Left(TABLE_SQL_BUILDER, TABLE_SQL_BUILDER.Length - 1) + ";";
// LOGTXT_WRITER(Environment.NewLine & "LAST REC > " & LAST_RECORD)
using (var cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(LAST_RECORD, CON_ONLINE))
{
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

TABLE_SQL_BUILDER = "";
LAST_RECORD = "";
CON_ONLINE.Close();
```

Comment: Why can't you just dump and store the dump on some object store?

Comment: it gonna sound stupid but belive me or not i never thought to do this, actually that was a great idea i used an ftp client to upload the file to the server instead of writing the whole data to the database

Comment: The professional way to do it is to use proper backup software, of which there are many. Recommendations are off-topic for [so], maybe try [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: One thing you'll want to implement as soon as you can is some sort of "encryption at rest" so that if your object store gets hit/dumped you're not going to leak client data. If the client has some kind of key, and importantly, some kind of "recovery code" they can use if their computer catches fire, etc. that'd be ideal. You're only holding encrypted backups you can't read at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way to backup data on remote servers is to upload the dump file to the server preferably to FTP server instead of writing the whole data to the database online

you can use FtpWebRequest to upload the file to the server here is the code just in case you need it

```
 var url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip";
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  

using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    fileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
}
```